# Algorithm to compute the fifth root of a positive real number

Tags: numerical-methods, newton-raphson

I'm trying to solve this problem:

> Devise a Newton algorithm for computing the fifth root of any positive real number.

What I'm trying to do is to make an analogy with the algorithm to compute the square root of a positive real number. We now that if $x = \sqrt{\alpha}$ then $x^2 = \alpha$, and $x = \dfrac{\alpha}{x}$. Having this in mind, the Newton algorithm for computing the square root of $\alpha$ is

$$ x_{n+1} = \dfrac{1}{2}\left( x_n + \dfrac{\alpha}{x_n} \right) $$

so, I have tried to find a recursion formula beginnig at $x = \sqrt[5]{\alpha}$, but I can't find this formula yet.

Thanks for your advices!

Comment: well, how did you get $x^2 = \alpha$?

Comment: Doing $x^2 = (\sqrt{\alpha})^2 = \alpha$, because $\alpha > 0$

Comment: so which equation do you get for $x=\sqrt[5]{\alpha}$?

Comment: I've been trying to express $x = \sqrt[5]{\alpha}$ as $x^5 = \alpha$, thus, $x = \dfrac{\alpha}{x^4}$, but I'm not quite sure if this is a good statement.

Comment: Try to apply the Newton method to this equation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The find the
$n^{th}$ root of $a$,
we want to solve
$x^n = a$,
or
$x^n-a = 0$.

Let $f(x)
= x^n-a$.
Then
$f'(x)
=nx^{n-1}
$.

Since Newton's iteration is
$x \leftarrow
x-\frac{f(x)}{f'(x)}
$,
this becomes
$x
\leftarrow
x-\frac{x^n-a}{nx^{n-1}}
=x-(\frac{x}{n}-\frac{a}{nx^{n-1}})
=\frac1{n}((n-1)x+\frac{a}{x^{n-1}})
$.

Answer (score 2):

Try  this weighted mean;
$$x_{n+1}=\frac15\Bigl(4x_n+\frac{\alpha}{x_n^4}\Bigr).$$

Comment: Maybe I'm wrong, but can we generalize this: to compute the $n$-th root of a positive number we could do

$$ x_{n+1} = \dfrac{1}{n}\left( x_n + \dfrac{(n-1)x_n}{x_n^{n-1}} \right) $$

Comment: the $4$ is in front of the wrong term :)

Comment: @Alexei0709: avoid using $n$ to denote $2$ different things. The generaliosation should be $\;\frac1r\Bigl((r-1)x_n+\dfrac{\alpha}{x_n^{r-1}$.

Comment: Bernard, you're right! Sorry the mistake

Comment: @user251257: Thanks for pointing the error! I must say I only superficially checked if  a fixed point of the function  was the 5-th root.